# Add divider to context menu on tray icon

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

I want add divider between context menu items on system tray icon. This is my code:

```
    ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
    cm.MenuItems.Add("Resume", new EventHandler(MenuResume_Click));
    cm.MenuItems.Add(); // Here i want the divider
    cm.MenuItems.Add("Logout", new EventHandler(BTNExit_Click));
    cm.MenuItems.Add("Logout and Quit", new EventHandler(BTNExit_Compl));

    this.Hide();
    NIControlPanel.Visible = true;
    NIControlPanel.ContextMenu = cm;
```

Divider like is this one >> https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgksW.png

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349856/how-do-you-add-a-separator-to-a-winforms-menu-in-c

Answer (score 1):

cm.MenuItems.Add(new ToolStripSeparator()); should work